# Dual accounts in MacOS, work and personal for audit purposes?

Tags: macos, active-directory

We're bringing in ISO 27001 at my company so one of the things we have to be able to do is audit the software installed on peoples machines.

Is it possible with MacOS to have seperate accounts for work and personal use such that there is no cross contamination between the two sides so people can use their machines for work and home?

Especially looking for a way that could work with Azure Active Directory and allow access to audit installed apps remotely.

Comment: Yes, macOS can have multiple user accounts, and so you could make separate personal and work accounts. Is your question more about more fully isolating two user accounts from each other because of specific audit requirements? Like, are you asking for ways for the personal account's home directory to be separately encrypted, so the auditors can't violate the user's privacy? Or are you asking for ways to make sure the user never messes with files in the his work account's home directory when logged into his home account?

Comment: I want to make sure one account can't affect or access data on the other under any circumstances

Comment: Do you require either account to have admin privileges? There will always be ways for an account with admin privileges to mess with other accounts, except maybe if you separately encrypt each user's home directory, which is complicated. Also, how do you feel about accounts affecting each other via shared parts of the system, like putting shared files in /Users/Shared ?